# StandardWatchEvents.ENTRY_MODIFY triggers with modifying a subfolder?

Tags: java, io, watchservice

Example:
I have my desktop with a subfolder "Desktop/sub"

if only Desktop is registered and once started the WatchService I modify the content of a subfolder.. should it trigger an ENTRY_MODIFY or not? I tried and it does not. It works only for modifying a file within the registered folder (Desktop in this case).

Just asking this question because in a mock exam for OCPJP7 it says that actually even modifying a subfolder such as "Desktop/sub" for example removing a file within "Desktop/sub" it should trigger the event.

However again, I have tried it out and it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
WatchKey key = ws.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

if (key ==null)
{
    continue;
}
List<WatchEvent<?>> lista = key.pollEvents();

for (WatchEvent<?> event : lista)
{
    switch(event.kind().toString())
    {
    case "ENTRY_CREATE": System.out.println("There has been a creation over here: "+event.context());break;
    case "ENTRY_MODIFY": System.out.println("There has been a modification over here: "+event.context());break;
    case "ENTRY_DELETE": System.out.println("There has been a deletion over here: "+event.context());

    }

    key.reset();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `WatchService` only looks at the file and folder modifications in the registered `Path`s.

If you registered

```
WatchService service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
Path path = Paths.get("/Desktop");
path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

Then adding a folder to `Desktop` will be seen. Changing a file in `Desktop` will be seen. Adding a folder to `Desktop/Subs` will also be seen, because the folder `Subs` inside `Desktop` was modified. However, modifying a file in `Desktop/Subs` will not be seen because that path is not registered with the service.

You can always register all the paths under `Desktop` recursively

```
private void registerRecursive(final Path root) throws IOException {
    // register all subfolders
    Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                dir.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

I have not tried on Linux but the following works on Windows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   

    WatchService service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    Path path = Paths.get("/Desktop");
    path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    WatchKey key = null;
    while(true) {
        key = service.take();

        List<WatchEvent<?>> lista = key.pollEvents();

        for (WatchEvent<?> event : lista)
        {
            switch(event.kind().toString())
            {
            case "ENTRY_CREATE": System.out.println("There has been a creation over here: "+event.context());break;
            case "ENTRY_MODIFY": System.out.println("There has been a modification over here: "+event.context());break;
            case "ENTRY_DELETE": System.out.println("There has been a deletion over here: "+event.context());

            }

            key.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to add both a file and a directory to Desktop/sub and ENTRY.MODIFY did not trigger anything. However it works if I modify a file in the Desktop. The code I use is above posted. I am using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @Rollerball Which `StandardWatchEventKinds` have you declared?

Comment: all of them, if I modify a file in the Desktop it does trigger the event

Comment: only if I add a file or remove a file/directory in Desktop/Sub it does not trigger anything.

Comment: You should be registering your path as `path.register(service, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE);`. Where `path` is a `Path` object for `/Desktop`. Adding or deleting a file in `Desktop/Sub` will trigger an event. Please double check you have the correct `WatchService` setup.

Comment: Double checked and I also told you that modifying a file in Desktop it triggers it.

Comment: I am thinking that it might be operating system dependent, I am on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @ROllerball On windows, yes it triggers them, with the code I've added in my last edit. I doubt linux would prevent that functionality. I would think its guaranteed by the API even if the underlying implementation is different.

Comment: mm I see. I have super double checked and unless I use the recursive way. It does not trigger for a change in a subdirectory of the registered directory.. at this point I would like to hear another user using linux